# Laravel / Nginx serving wrong site

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have tried everything.

I recently tried to deploy a new Laravel application on my Ubuntu Digital Ocean droplet. I have done this many times in the past and have done nothing out of the ordinary with this project. I'm using https://gist.github.com/jamieshepherd/50419bb148a4f43e8266 this as a template nginx configuration, which I base all of my sites off. However, this time I deployed and went to my domain, I was served another client's site. The site had no images, styles, scripts etc. - but sure enough this was the wrong site. Weirdly, I could go to /images/example.jpg and get the correct file which would be in /public/images/example.jpg - but the actual routes were being served from a completely different folder.

There is absolutely no reference to the other client in my project anywhere, I feel like it has something to do with Laravel or PHP5-FPM setting some kind of root directory to the other folder.

I have gone to /public/index.php and just echo and died a message, and **this works fine**. When I revert the change and let the application run it again displays the other client's application. Here's a list of other things I've tried.

- Temporarily renaming the other client's folder, as expected, NewSite throws a 404 error
- Temporarily disabling the other client's nginx block, NewSite continues to serve the other client's site (remember, not css/images/scripts, weirdly)
- Reinstalling PHP5-FPM
- Printing the document_root, everything looks normal (/web/NewSite/public)
- Trying to run the site off a different port
- Pulled a working Laravel application from a completely different server, put it on this server, set the domain to point to this working application, serves the other client's site
- Grep'd for any references to the client site in any of the project folders just to check I wasn't going insane, confirmed I'm not insane, though after all this I'm not sure anymore

Really I'm lost, I have no idea how to debug this any more.

Site trying to deploy: http://paragon.gg

Client site view that it's servring: https://swellhunter.co.uk

Client site NGINX conf: https://gist.github.com/jamieshepherd/4ff5430ddb13ed04f22c

**Edit: Update:** To make matters even more bizarre. I have temporarily removed swellhunter from sites-enabled, visited paragon.gg, still serves swellhunter's index. WHAT? There is absolutely no reference to the site at all now, I've even moved the paragongg folder to a completely different place to check. How on earth is it even finding the view with no reference to go on?

Comment: Do you have the nginx file for paragon.gg? Only swellhunter.co.uk is shown.

Comment: Yep it's the first link shown.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with Laravel rather than with nginx or with your VPS.
Since you pointed out simple PHP file is pointing out rightly.
SSH to your droplet and run you laravel app using php artisan serve.
And access your droplet on port:3000
If the problem persists you can rule out server issues and can concentrate on debugging laravel app. Maybe be there is something wrong with you laravel app itself, some unwanted changes etc. Did you verify your laravel App?

Comment: I thought it might be, but as I said I took a working Laravel app from an entirely different server and pointed the domain to it, and still served the client view. I'm unsure what you mean by verify my app?

Comment: By verify I just meant to say if you checked your app of any  potential bugs. Is php artisan serve giving out the same problem?

Comment: Oh yes it works fine locally through Homestead, php artisan serve I can't connect to on the droplet.

Comment: Then it seems likes nginx error, it may be difficult to debug like this, I could provide assistance directly if you wish to through team viewer. since its quite difficult to guess the issue.

Comment: or you can add me as a team member to your digital ocean account and I can help you debug it

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot of confidential information on here so wouldn't be able to give or show you access to the droplet. I appreciate the offer though.

Comment: can you confirm if you run multiple sites on same droplet?

Comment: Yes. I have a few droplets all with multiple sites on them. They all work correctly except this one. If you read the latest update it'll explain why this problem is particularly strange.

Comment: thats really bizzare!

Comment: Did you try Changing the port on which paragon.gg is served? I think it might even be a conflicting port since I see both of the sites conf use port 80. Just in case did you try serving paragon.gg on a diferrent port?

Comment: Yep, that's something in my "here's things I've tried" list..

"- Trying to run the site off a different port"

Comment: Sorry din't notice that was thinking of the issue from scratch, now thats really weird in any case.

Comment: I'm just trying to think how it is even pulling in a view from another folder, if the site isn't even enabled in nginx. That makes no sense to me, the only thing I can think of is caching but there is no caching configured on this droplet.

Comment: Have you checked your CNAME, A,AAA records of your domain? are they pointing out to the right IP and port?

Comment: this link looks relevant to you though cause might not be the same the issue is similar https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/www-pointed-to-wrong-server-block-ubuntu-nginx

Comment: DNS are correct yeah, I use the same records for all of my other sites

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste an LS -l of the directory? Have you checked to see what you have in the Laravel app/config/app.php for url ? I just took a look at paragon.gg and put https://paragon.gg it gave me a cert error but after I accepted it the site looked fine. Is that not the result you wanted?

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/jamieshepherd/e0467742bb8841331010 - paragon.gg is in my app config. These are all things that are nullified by the fact that I've tried pointing the domain to another, already working application, with the same issue. - And no, the paragon.gg site is not the same as the paddleboarding website "swell hunter" - as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: On my laravel nginx install I have www-data as the group. is your root running your nginx install?

Comment: Dumb question but did you create the symlink for sites-enabled from this config? or are you running all your sites from the same default config?

Comment: Separate config for each site, symlinked to sites-enabled

Comment: And you restarted the nginx service?

Comment: Yes, this is not my first rodeo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101228/discussion-between-cie-and-jamie-shepherd).